# Grid stopping at 10 x 50 instead of 50 x 50

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to generate a grid that's 50x50 using the drawing panel but for some reason it stops at 50x10. I'm using Intellij if that's relevant.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    int theChangingX = 0;
    int theChangingY = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row <= 2500 + 1; row++){
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawRect(theChangingX,theChangingY, pixelsize, pixelsize );
        theChangingX+=10;
        for (int col = 0; col<=2500 + 1; col++ ){
            if (theChangingX ==2500){
                theChangingY+=10;
                theChangingX =-10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ```theChangingX =-10;``` could it be you meant ```theChangingX -=10;```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Think you are over complicating the code, I would go with something like that:

```
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    for (int col = 0; col < 50; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < 50; row++) {
            g.drawRect(row * cellSize, col * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm dumb. Thanks for the help dawg.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    int theChangingX = 0;
    int theChangingY = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < 50; row++){
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        theChangingX = row*10;

        for (int col = 0; col < 50 ;col++ ){
            theChangingY = col*10;
            g.drawRect(theChangingX,theChangingY, pixelsize, pixelsize );
        }
    }
}
```